# "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update. Database or object is read-only" Error while reading from .Dat file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, oledbconnection

I am trying to read .Dat text file with Microsoft Jet Engine provider but getting "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.'" Error at ExcecuteReader.
My code looks like the below

```
 public static void ReadDatFile()
        {
            var query = "select * from VehiclePositions.dat";
            var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\lenovo\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\;Extended Properties='text;ReadOnly=False'");
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            var test=command.ExecuteReader();

            while(test.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
            }
        }
```

I tried adding HDR=NO;FMT=FixedLength to extended properties but the issue persist, I am not really sure what am I missing here.

Comment: No, file is closed everywhere else .

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is caused by the extension .dat on your file.

Some research on internet has given me a clue about what to look for.  In the registry the Text driver used by OleDb looks at the following key:

(Note the WOW6432Node used by 32bit drivers in a 64bit OS)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\Extensions
```

In this registry key are listed the extensions allowed for files opened
by the text driver. The default ones are

```
txt,csv,tab,asc
```

So, if you change that file to *VehiclePosition.txt* then it works.
Or you can add the *,dat* at the end of the registry key and event the current filename will work.

Of course, you should have a *schema.ini* in your folder where you add the following lines

```
[VehiclePositions.dat]
Format=FixedLength
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=F1 Text Width 8
Col2=F2 Text Width 4
Col.........
```

For a full description of the Schema.ini keys and format you could refer to this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)